# How can I update a database row using DatabaseManager Class and EFDBContext?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

db is a EFDBContext class, I can create an object of delete an object but how can I update an object?

Example:

```
public void CreateProject(Project projectToCreate)
    {
        db.Project.Add(projectToCreate);
    }
```

Or is it only possible by deleting it en recreate it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update something you could fetch it, update the properties you want and finally save the changes:

```
public void Update()
{
    var projectToUpdate = db.Project.Find(idOfTheProjectToUpdate);
    projectToUpdate.Foo = "new Foo";
    projectToUpdate.Bar = "new Bar";
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

As an alternative if you already have the object to be updated you could attach it to the context:

```
projectToUpdate.Foo = "new Foo";
projectToUpdate.Bar = "new Bar";

db.Project.Attach(projectToUpdate);
var entry = db.Entry(projectToUpdate);
entry.Property(e => e.Foo).IsModified = true;
entry.Property(e => e.Bar).IsModified = true;
db.SaveChanges();
```